# What are the difference between PHP 8 Match expression vs PHP 7 switch case?

Tags: php, switch-statement, match, php-8, version-compatibility

**PHP 8 Match expression code**

```
echo match (8.0) {
    '8.0' => "Oh no!",
     8.0 => "This is what I expected",
};
//> This is what I expected
```

**PHP 7 switch code**

```
switch (8.0) {
  case '8.0':
    $result = "Oh no!";
    break;
  case 8.0:
    $result = "This is what I expected";
    break;
}
echo $result;
//> Oh no!
```

1. Which one give better performance?
2. Use case of match and switch.

Comment: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/match_expression_v2

Comment: There's a nice article about comparison: https://stitcher.io/blog/php-8-match-or-switch

Answer (score 14):

Main differences:

- match is an expression, while switch is statement
- match uses strict comparison, while switch uses loose
- match evaluates only one value, while switch may evaluate more (depending on break statement)
- match allows only single-line expression, while switch allows block of statements

Match expression has got already its page in the PHP documentation if you want to know more:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php

> The match expression branches evaluation based on an identity check of a value. Similarly to a switch statement, a match expression has a subject expression that is compared against multiple alternatives. Unlike switch, it will evaluate to a value much like ternary expressions. Unlike switch, the comparison is an identity check (===) rather than a weak equality check (==). Match expressions are available as of PHP 8.0.0.

Comment: Furthermore, `match` throws if `default` is missing and no arms are matched.